# How to covert youtube link into embed link in Laravel and validate that field should contain only youtube link

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="">
  <label for="fname">You tube link1:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="youtube_link" name="youtube_link" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eKVizvYSUQ"><br>
  <label for="lname">you tubelink 2:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="youtube_link2" name="youtube_link2" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eKVizvYSUQ"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

here i want to convert the youtube link into  embed link in laravel at same time field should contain only youtube links (validation).how to do both in laravel.
contoller

```
   public function youtube(Request $request)
   {
     if ($request->ajax())
     {
       $rules = [
         'youtube_link'=>'?',
          'youtube_link2'=>'?',
        ];
         ...
      }
    
   }
```

when i click submit i am passing the form data through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept only the parameter after `v=` and keep the field as required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

 <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

  <form action="">
  <label for="fname">You tube link1:</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="youtube_link" name="youtube_link" 
  value="0eKVizvYSUQ"><br>
 <label for="lname">you tubelink 2:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="youtube_link2" name="youtube_link2" 
  value="0eKVizvYSUQ"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form> 
 </body>
```

Now to in validation just put required

```
        public function youtube(Request $request)
   {
     if ($request->ajax())
     {
       $rules = [
         'youtube_link'=>'required',
          'youtube_link2'=>'required',
        ];
         ...
      }
    
   }
```

to convert embed links concatenate the input as follows

```
   $data['youtube_link'] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $request
                          ->youtube_link
    $data['youtube_link2'] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $request
      ->youtube_link2
```

To display create an iframe like

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="{{$data->youtube_link}}" 
  title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
 clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
 allowfullscreen> 
 </iframe>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the embed is not working any other way is there ?.for validation is required is fine but field should contain only youtube link not other . what validation we can use for that ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eKVizvYSUQ so how i can separate the parameter from this link

Answer (score 0):

To verify url parameters you can use the parse_url() method as folows

```
 $link_1 = parse_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eKVizvYSUQ");
```

This will return an array of url parameters like

```
   array:4 [▼
         "scheme" => "https"
         "host" => "www.youtube.com"
         "path" => "/watch"
         "query" => "v=0eKVizvYSUQ"
         ]
```

now you can write your own logic to verify. It may solve your problem.